# mongodb 2.2.3 has issues with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb on local server 2.2.2 and aws 2.2.3
on local I am executing an aggregate with group and gets the result
on AWS the same script causes
{ "errmsg" : "no such cmd", "ok" : 0 }

here is the script

```
.aggregate({$group:{_id:'type'}})
```

Thanks

Comment: All I can think of is that AWS is not actually installed with 2.2.3 and maybe it is using the 2.2.3 shell or something

Comment: on aws:

mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3

on local:
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2

Comment: ok I got it the db version is old not sure why going to reinstall it ; when I run mongod it shows: db version v1.0.1

Comment: @user1560750 Have you resolved the issue?